# Why is the class creating an object with possibilities property undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, syntax, promise, async-await

I'm trying to check an `object` (customer) against another `object` (developers), there are multiple developers so I have an `object` which houses all of them and I'm iterating through `object` that holds the developer, when a customer tests positive for the age condition then a test string is pushed onto the `gateKeeper`. `possibilities` property and in turn creates a new customer `object` from the customer `class` however, when I run `gatekeeper.build(prospect, developers)` pass it to a variable and `console.log` that `variable` it shows the possibilities properly as `undefined`, but when I `console.log` from inside the `promise` it shows it passed, for both developers, meaning it is pushing 'worked' onto the possibilities property but it isn't using that value when It builds the `class`, why?

**edit**
This now does as expected, I replaced the promise chain with a callback chain however as I understand it; the promise syntax paired with async await is the most correct way to execute functions when the timing of execution is important. I think I might be missing something as it regards to promises because code running within the promise chain executes but doesn't seem to affect anything outside the promise chain. If this is the case then (in my limited experience lol) I can't see any use case for the promises or the async await syntax, can someone please help me clarify this?

```
  age: 28,
  income: 75,
  maritalStatus: 'Married',
  majorCc: 'Y',
  zipCode: 32805,
  possibilities: {}
};

var developers = {
  westgate: {
    name: 'Westgate',
    aTop: 68,
    aBot: 28,
    income: 50,
    majorCc: 'Not Required',
    maritalStatus: ['Married', 'Co Hab'],
    payload: ['Myrtle Beach', 'Orlando', 'Gatlinburg', 'Cocoa Beach']
  },
  bluegreen: {
    name: 'Bluegreen',
    aTop: 999,
    aBot: 25,
    income: 50,
    majorCc: 'Not Required',
    maritalStatus: ['Married', 'Single Male', 'Co Hab', 'Single Female'],
    payload: ['Myrtle Beach', 'Orlando', 'Gatlinburg', 'Cocoa Beach']
  },
};

let gateKeeper = {
  prospect: {},
  settings: {},
  possibilities: [],
  methods: {
    age(callback1) {
      if (gateKeeper.prospect.age >= gateKeeper.settings.aBot && gateKeeper.prospect.age <= gateKeeper.settings.aTop) {
        callback1();
      }
    },
    income(callback) {
      if (gateKeeper.prospect.income >= gateKeeper.settings.income) {
        callback();
      }
    },
    createPayload() {
      var cache = {};
      cache[gateKeeper.settings.name] = gateKeeper.settings.payload;
      gateKeeper.possibilities.push(cache);
    },

    packageMethods() {
      gateKeeper.methods.age(() => {
        gateKeeper.methods.income(() => {
          gateKeeper.methods.createPayload();
        });
      });
    }
  },

  resources: class customer {
    constructor(prospectInput, developerInput) {
      this.age = prospectInput.age;
      this.income = prospectInput.income;
      this.maritalStatus = prospectInput.maritalStatus;
      this.majorCc = prospectInput.majorCc;
      this.zipCode = prospectInput.zipCode;
      this.possibilities = developerInput; //MUST BE A DICTIONARY WITH ARRAY OF LOCATIONS
    }
  },
  build(prospectInput, developersInput) {
    var payload;
    gateKeeper.prospect = prospectInput;
    for (var i in developersInput) {
      gateKeeper.settings = developersInput[i];
      payload = gateKeeper.prospect;
      gateKeeper.methods.packageMethods();
    }
    return new gateKeeper.resources(gateKeeper.prospect, gateKeeper.possibilities);
  }
};


var test = gateKeeper.build(prospect, developers);
console.log(test.possibilities[1].Bluegreen[3]);
```

Comment: `possiblilies !== possibilities` first one is a typo, use the second instead.

Comment: another typo in : `gateKeeper.possibilites.push('worked');` ( `possibilites` )

Comment: Your use of promises makes no sense. Nothing in `income` or `packages` is asynchronous.

Comment: Repeatedly assigning to the same `gateKeeper.settings` in that loop makes no sense, and neither does the `payload` variable that you are not using anywhere.

Comment: gatekeeper settings are the variables compared to prospect, in the first loop it compares with Bluegreen (this object contains many more developers in real life this is just test data), then in the second it compares to Westgate, if this is an incorrect way to do this please let me know the correct way; I am new and am eager to improve my skills.